# Django 1.11 can we create relationship between tables from two different databases?

Tags: django

In my project I'm trying to create central DB service with multiple database so here my question is can we create relationship between tables from two different databases?

Example:

MySQL DB1.table user

```
class User(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()
```

MySQLDb2.table post

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = model.CharField()
     user= models.Forignkey(User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't support relationships across databases, and only officially supports a single schema within a database. While there may be ways to hack something like this up, depending on your flavor of database, it is not recommended.

I've done some work with hacks to have multiple schemata in Django, and it isn't pretty.

You may want to read this part of the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases

Good luck!