# Error in Connecting Multiple Database Django ( 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type' )

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, geodjango, django-settings

I am using multiple databases in Django,

On the current server, PostGIS is installed and am trying to connect POSTGRESQL from another server,

**settings.py**

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'db_name_1',
        'USER': 'user_name_1',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'users_db' : {
        'NAME' : 'db_name_2',
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST' : '',
        'PORT' : '',
        'USER' : 'user_name_2',
        'PASSWORD' : '',
    },
    # 'users_db' : dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://user_name_2:password_2@host_2:0000/db_name_2')
}
```

Now as per documentation.

**Error**

```sh
python3 manage.py migrate --database='users_db'
```

```py
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'
```

**UPDATE**

As per other StackOverflow pages, I found `dj-database-url` i used it but still problem persists.

for `dj-database-url`

```
'users_db' : dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://user_name_2:password_2@host_2:0000/db_name_2')
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to migrate geospatial enabled objects to non geospatial database...when connected another database contrib.gis.db.backend.postgis should be on the second database to only the host and ports are to change

Comment: Thanks for the reply, they are on two different servers. So technically this problem should not come.

Comment: The error that is being displayed is when the HOST and PORT are different for both of them.

Comment: Have a look at the engine for the two database...why are you using different engines one for spatial and one for non spatial

Comment: Yes, I got your point now i have converted both the Db into PostGIS, Now its working.

Comment: Also i found this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/59879983/7999665 which confirms.